# Terraform can't create a CloudFront's origin with a static S3 website endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a plan which uses two modules: `bucket-website` and `cloudfront-website`

Among other things (policies and such) inside the bucket module, there is the following resource for creating the bucket and serve it as a website:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket-website" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
  region = "${var.region}"

  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
  }

  tags = "${local.common_tags}"
}
```

Also this module has the following output:

```
output "website_endpoint" {
  value = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket-website.website_endpoint}"
}
```

The `cloudfront-website` module has a resource with all those cloudfront properties (IPs, cache stuff, etc), but the relevant part is:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "distribution" {
.....
  origin {
    domain_name = "${var.domain_name}"
    origin_id   = "${var.domain_name}"
  }
.....
}
```

The call to the cloudfront module in the plan passes the following parameter:

```
domain_name = "${module.bucket-website.website_endpoint}"
```

I can confirm that the value is correct, because in the log of `terraform apply` is can see:

```
  origin.123456.domain_name: "" => "foo.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
  origin.123456.origin_id:   "" => "foo.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Which is the same endpoint I would use if I was doing this setup using just the AWS Console, i.e. get the bucket's static web endpoint (**different to the standard bucket endpoint**) and use it as the origin of Cloudfront.

However, for some reason Terraform is complaining about the domain name:

```
 * aws_cloudfront_distribution.distribution: error creating CloudFront Distribution: InvalidArgument: The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket.
```

And I'm already out of ideas. Everything looks good. The endpoint is correct. I have checked other examples and they also use `${aws_s3_bucket.<BUCKET_RESOURCE_NAME>.website_endpoint}`, so I honestly don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just found the solution. When serving a S3 website through CloudFront, the following code must be added to the `origin` section, even though it's not specified elsewhere to do so.

```
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = "80"
      https_port             = "443"
      origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
    }
```

Comment: How do you solve the problem of creating an Origin Access Identity so that only the CloudFront distro can access your S3 bucket?

Comment: I think you need to do that in the bucket policy by assigning the distro arn for resource property (Identifiers). It is a guess. Can confirm if anyone is looking for the exact configuration in terraform.